# Text Size AppBar / NavBar Accessibility

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, accessibility, android-bottomnav

The accessibility features in Android enables text size and display components to be enlarged but it seems that some of the native components don't quite allow this to occur as expected.

2 queries:

1. This image shows a brand new bottom navigation activity layout. Because the options are too big for the textviews they spill over with a dash at the end. Is this accessible?

[Default Bottom Navigation Bar Activity Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OTiR.jpg)

2. Is the App Bar text view accessible from a text size/scaling aspect? On some apps I find the header text expands beyond the bounds of the App Bar itself.

Answer (score 0):

Emailed Google Accessibility, they told me to download the Android Accessibility Checker application and check there. Running it on the example applications produced no errors so can confirm that both are accessible despite the ellipsis on the tab bar items and non-scaling of the action bar text.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of your question, Android's "Font size"/"Large text" settings do not adjust the text size of the title text inside native top app bars. This appears to be deliberate behaviour.